# T-SQL stuck on scope_identity return from stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm sure this is a easy fix, but I can't find an answer here. Been many a years since I have written stored procedures..

These are my procedures:

This first one works, and returns the newly created Id.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_CreateBytegymType]
    @Name NVARCHAR(200),
    @Type NCHAR(1),
    @Description NVARCHAR(MAX) NULL,
    @Comment NVARCHAR(MAX) NULL,
    @Source NVARCHAR(MAX) NULL,
    @BtId INT OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    INSERT INTO BytegymType
    VALUES (@Name, @Type, @Description, @Comment, @Source)

    SET @BtId = CAST(SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS INT)    
END
```

The second one calls the first one:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_CreateMuscle]
    @Name NVARCHAR(200),
    @Type NCHAR(1),
    @Description NVARCHAR(MAX) NULL,
    @Comment NVARCHAR(MAX) NULL,
    @Source NVARCHAR(MAX) NULL,
    @Group NVARCHAR(20) NULL
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @BtId int

    EXEC sp_CreateBytegymType
                @Name = @Name,
                @Type = @Type,
                @Description = @Description,
                @Comment = @Comment,
                @Source = @Source,
                @BtId = @BtId

    INSERT INTO Muscle
    VALUES (@BtId, @Group)
END
```

I get the following error:

> Msg 515, Level 16, State 2, Procedure sp_CreateMuscle, Line 20 [Batch Start Line 2]
>   Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'BtId'

Seems I'm not keeping the `@BtId` value. Do I need to put it into a new value after executing the `sp_CreateBytegymType`?

Also I would like to do this in a transactional manner. So if the the insert into Muscle fails, it should rollback the stored procedure insert.

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: Side note #2: `SCOPE_IDENTITY` already returns an `INT` (typically - if your identity column in the table is defined as an `INT`) - really no need to cast it to an `INT` when assigning it to `@BtId` ....

Comment: Re: Part (ii) of your question: See the examples "B" and "C" [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/try-catch-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#examples) ("Using TRY…CATCH in a transaction").

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add `OUTPUT`:

```
exec sp_CreateBytegymType
    @Name = @Name,
    @Type = @Type,
    @Description = @Description,
    @Comment = @Comment,
    @Source = @Source,
    @BtId = @BtId OUTPUT;
```

Also prefixing user defined stored procedures with `sp_` is not advised. Related article: [Is the sp_ prefix still a no-no?](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix)